# Email Open Rate is always 0.0%

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Although I have successfully received the test email and opened and clicked them, they are not tracked in the account, hence cannot be retrieved via SOAP request(OpenEvent).

Comment: This isn't normal - so something could be wrong with your email - or it could just be images were not displayed when the email was opened.  With out more information regarding the email's code it's hard to give suggestions.  Can you please provide us some additional detail?

Comment: How are you creating the email?  HTML paste? Have you inserted the tracking tag, that looks like this: <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"> ?

Answer (score 2):

I know, your question is pretty old, but as I also came across this problem, I'll share my answer here:

After checking that the tracking pixel is part of the E-Mail (can be easily done using a webmail client and the browser's developer tools), I figured out that in my case there were two reasons why it didn't work:

- First of all, I used an ad-blocker which blocked the tracking pixel, so make sure the pixel isn't blocked.
- After I disabled the ad-blocker I found out that the pixel couldn't be displayed because of an invalid ssl certificate being used. The custom domain used for email sends is also used for the tracking pixel (e.g. https://click.email.yourdomain.com), but a certificate for *.exacttarget.com is used.

So to install the correct certificate for your domain, it seems you need to contact the Marketing Cloud support. I found this salesforce knowledge article, which points out that an additional purchase is required to do so: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000232477&language=en_US